# JS on wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have created a page on wordpress and I have added some JavaScript.

Basically in wordpress on a page where you can input text of any sort weather this is HTML or just text are two tabs one called 'Visual' and 'text'. The 'Text' tab is where you add HTML and the script behind the page, this is where I have added some JavaScript but if someone’s goes on this page I have created and select the 'Visual' tab it breaks my code.

changes this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

    window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
                 }
    }
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
                 }
}   
</script>
```

changes it to this:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

    window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
                 }
}
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    for (var d = 0; d < dropdowns.length; d++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[d];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
                 }
   }

    // ]]></script>
```

Comment: You might be better of using a plugin or writing your own shortcode to insert JS as WordPress will try it's best to not let you just insert script tags as you have seen.  Check out this link they have some docs dedicated to this https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress specifically prevents non-admins from including JavaScript and iframes through the editor. It's done for security reasons, so various authors on your site can't paste in scripts you don't know or trust.

You can include this code in a custom plugin or your theme's functions.php file to enable it. It's not recommended, but it works. If you're the only person creating content on your site, it's probably not the end of the world if you use it:

```
// allow script & iframe tag within posts
function allow_post_tags( $allowedposttags ){
    $allowedposttags['script'] = array(
        'type' => true,
        'src' => true,
        'height' => true,
        'width' => true,
    );
    $allowedposttags['iframe'] = array(
        'src' => true,
        'width' => true,
        'height' => true,
        'class' => true,
        'frameborder' => true,
        'webkitAllowFullScreen' => true,
        'mozallowfullscreen' => true,
        'allowFullScreen' => true
    );
    return $allowedposttags;
}
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html','allow_post_tags', 1);
```

Automattic has [a plugin for adding JavaScript](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-javascript-editor/) to sites but it's going to add a couple extra steps vs just pasting the script in.

Ideally, though -- and this is what I really recommend -- you'd put the script in a file, then write a custom plugin or add code to your theme's functions.php file that [enqueues it through wp_enqueue_script](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-you-use-wp_enqueue_script). The leverages the WordPress API and lets you take advantage of plugins to [minify scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/) or take advantage of things like [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://wordpress.org/plugins/http2-server-push/).

Answer (score -1):

You should better make a separate .js file, and include it in your template page... Seems like JS is not supported on page edition...

Comment: The code works on the page fine until someone goes into the page and switches to the visual tab, thats when it breaks.

Comment: @JordonNew181 yeah, that's what I'm talking about. This feature is not made to use JS...

Comment: @JordonNew181 if you don't need the Visual tab you can disable it and you will not run into that issue.

Comment: The visual tab is need as other people work on the pages as well as myself.

Comment: @JordonNew181 yeah, so the answer is still the same: this feature is not made to use JS. So you'll have to write a separate .js file, and add it to the template or to your post as described in plasticpie's link...